# Knex and MySQL datetime field precision

Tags: mysql, node.js, bookshelf.js, knex.js

When using knex in a node application is there any way to set a MySQL datetime column as datetime(3) or datetime(6), or better yet set a default for all datetime columns including .timestamps?

Right now it looks like I'm getting the milliseconds truncated when I insert into the DB and then retrieve.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After asking about this exact situation on the [knex gitter channel](https://gitter.im/tgriesser/knex), I was pointed to the [`.specificType()`](http://knexjs.org/#Schema-specificType) function for handling this specific situation. So (in mysql, for example):

```
table.specificType('createdAt', 'DATETIME(6)');
```

would create a `DATETIME` column named `createdAt` with fractional seconds of up to 6 precision.  I will update this answer to confirm once I have had a chance to test with my local code.

UPDATE: This does indeed work as expected.

Comment: That was exactly what I needed.  Thanks!

The other thing I'd add is that I was previously using .timestamps() but switched over to:  
`table.specificType('created_at', 'DATETIME(3)')  
table.specificType('updated_at', 'DATETIME(3)')`  
which continues to work just fine in my codebase.

Comment: I tried using `knex.fn.now(6)` as the default value with the above solution, but was getting an error `Error: ER_INVALID_DEFAULT`. Using `knex.raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)')` worked.